# Servlet/Filters/Listeners in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've added Servlet/Filters/Listeners in Spring Boot application using ServletRegistrationBean , FilterRegistrationBean etc.. for that we have to declare servlets, filters as spring bean ..which will get added in Spring Application Context..which is working absolutely fine

My Question is ..whenever i will call my application, will the request FIRST be handled by Dispatcher Servlet and then to Filter?

Before spring boot, we use to register it directly in web.xml and then i think Filters used to handler the request first, then dispatcher servlet and so on and so forth..

Has the flow changed in Spring Boot Application?

Comment: It hasn't and never will as what is executed when is defined by the servlet spec...

Comment: Ok, so do you mean to say that in Spring Boot application also Filter will be executed first and then the request will go to Dispatcher Servlet even though the filters are registered as Spring Bean..??

Comment: The type of application doesn't matter... The order of what is executed when is determined by the servlet spec, which is implemented by Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow or whatever container you use. This has nothing to do with using (or not using) Spring Boot. If it is a web based application the order is predetermined on what type of components are executed in which order.